# EncodeBase64 in JAVA return a wrong output

Tags: java, base64, basic-authentication

I am building a web using Spring. I want to encode string to send as a Basic Authentication.

Here is the code,

```
private String authUsername = "admin";
private String authPassword = "admin"; 
private String unEncode = authUsername+authPassword;
private byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(unEncode.getBytes());
private String encode = new String(encodedBytes);   
private String authenCode = "Basic "+encode;
```

The result is "***Basic YWRtaW5hZG1pbg==***" And it is wrong.

The right output should be "***Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=***"

What I did wrong or What I missed ?

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think it is wrong? I can reproduce your "wrong" example both in code and on www.base64encode.org - my guess is that your "right output" is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in the Base64-encoding but in constructing your string. Basic-Authentication requires `username:password` but your are missing the `:`.